# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed

Tags: magento2

Please anyone see my code and resolve this issue

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   MyClass::__construct() must implement interface
>   Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface, none given, called
>   in
>   /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/shipping.phtml
>   on line 132 and defined in
>   /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/shipping.phtml:109
>   Stack trace: #0

```
    use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface as CoreSession;

    class MyClass
    {

        protected $_coreSession;

        public function __construct(CoreSession $coreSession) 
        {
            $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;

        }

      public function setValue($total_cost){
        $this->_coreSession->start();
        $this->_coreSession->setMessage($total_cost);


    }

    public function getValue(){
        $this->_coreSession->start();
        return $this->_coreSession->getMessage();


    }


}

$myclas = new MyClass();

 $myclas.setValue($total_cost);     
 echo $myclas.getValue();
```

Comment: `$myclas = new MyClass();

 $myclas.setValue($total_cost);     
 echo $myclas.getValue();` use is not good idea

Comment: just want to echo varaible or get variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue at `$myclas = new MyClass();`

To initialize this class you have to use the object manager or have to inject that class to your class.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$myclass = $objectManager->create('{NameSpaceofClass}\MyClass');
```

Comment: how can i echo myclass on same  phtml file

Comment: `$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$myclass = $objectManager->create('{NameSpaceofClass}\MyClass');
$myclas.setValue($total_cost);     
echo $myclas.getValue();`

Comment: NOte that  you have set value  and get value on same time, it does not work, set value of session , will reflect one page  refresh as Session is server site element

Answer (score 1):

simply run di compile

`php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile`

AND

`php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush`

OR just run this command

If you are using Magento 2.1.9 or less than clear/remove

`rm -rf var/generation folder`

for above magento version run below command

`rm -rf generated`

and check your output again

Comment: nothing happend same issue after run those commands

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: If you are using Magento 2.1.9 or less than clear/remove  var/generation folder

Comment: version magento 2......

Comment: nothing happend

Comment: tried with php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: nothing gonna work same issue

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your constructor with this and let's check if it works,

```
 public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
    ) {
        $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
    }
```

As we are directly passing the SessionManagerInterface class in the constructor we don't need to include it.

Now run the following commands

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: nothing gonna work same issue

Answer (score 0):

Set/Get/Unset Value in Core Session:

```
protected $_coreSession;

public function __construct(
    -----
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
    ){
    $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
    ----
}

public function setValue($total_cost){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    $this->_coreSession->setMessage($total_cost);
}

public function getValue(){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    return $this->_coreSession->getMessage();
}

public function unSetValue(){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    return $this->_coreSession->unsMessage();
}
```

after this **Run this SSH Command**

```
  1. rm -rf var/*
  2. rm -rf generated/*
```